# LED Labeling Question

Tags: led

I have an LED.  The LED is listed as 3 Watt with a Forward Voltage of 3.2-3.4V and a Forward Current of 700mA.

Wouldn't this make it a \$3.4V*0.7A=2.38W\$ LED?  If so is it common practice for a 3W LED to be closer to 2W.
Thanks

EDIT: This was a purchase from ebay.  There is no 'complete' data sheet available.  The one I have is composed mostly of product dimensions, with the only relevant numbers being the ones already provided.

http://www.ebay.com/itm/122469513514?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&var=422924889580&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT

Comment: Link to the datasheet?  That seems a bit disingenuous and not typical of a reputable manufacturer.

Comment: where did you buy it?

Comment: Add a part number and link to datasheet in your question.

Comment: You are making way too much out of this. But before a better answer about why can be provided, you need to provide the exact LED (and/or datasheet link) so that someone can help you understand the reasoning using datasheet information that you can see for yourself.

Comment: With these LEDs you should largely **ignore the voltage** and focus on the **current**. LEDs have very unpredictable voltages. If it is rated 3 Watt and 700mA then the voltage will be roughly 3/0.7 = 4.3 V but again, that does not matter much. If you want to operate the LED at 3 W, give it 700 mA. If you want to use it at 1.5 W, give it 350 mA.

Comment: My guess is that the 3W is a maximum rating, and the forward voltage is a typical value.

Comment: You lucky you didn't get a 0.2 mW led.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can find a datasheet for the LED, you will typically find that there is a peak current rating that is higher than the continuous current rating. The peak current will be conditioned by a maximum pulse width and duty cycle.

When operated at peak current, the LED will also have a higher (peak) voltage drop. It is this combination from which the three watt rating is derived.

Comment: This sounds potentially plausible.  I have no peak current or voltage numbers for the LED so I can't confirm.